# Objective-C - Using blocks and memory management?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I was reading the documentation on Grand Central Dispatch, and there are two functions called `Block_copy` and `Block_release`.
According to the documentation these methods are being used while calling `dispatch_async` to take care of the memory management of the block. Am I suppose to do the same thing in my code?

Is there a problem with my code below?

```
typedef void (^MyCompletionHandler)(NSError *error)

@interface ServiceClient

- (void)fetchWithCompletionHandler:(MyCompletionHandler)completionHandler;

@property (nonatomic, assign) MyCompletionHandler completionHandler;

@end

@implementation ServiceClient
@synthesize completionHandler = _completionHandler;

- (void)fetchWithCompletionHandler:(MyCompletionHandler)completionHandler 
{
   self.completionHandler = completionHandler;
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchInBackground)];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) MyCompletionHandler completionHandler;
```

With `assign` your block will not be retained, but `copy` will perform `Block_copy` automatically.

Comment: Is there a problem with using strong instead of copy? Why would I want a copy when I could retain the object?

Comment: As I know, an Objective-C runtime treats `strong` the same as `copy` for blocks. And `copy` with blocks means a different thing than `copy` with objects. I would advise to read this article on subject: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1749597

Comment: @Stream `strong` is not treated the same as `copy` – the latter will guarantee that a block is on or moved to the heap _and then also retained_, while the former will only guarantee that it is retained (and thus might still be on the stack).

Answer (score 2):

You should copy blocks when assigning them to variables -- in this case you could either change your `completionHandler` property to have `(nonatomic, copy)` attributes, or use `Block_copy` when assigning the block, like you said.

Comment: but from my understanding the objective-C level copy is not the same as the c level copy functions. They are completely different. So does changing the property to copy would do the job properly? Is it going to trigger Block_copy to get called?

Comment: From the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW2

Comment: @aryaxt: `Block_copy(someBlock)` is the same as `[someBlock copy]`; and `Block_release(someBlock)` is the same as `[someBlock release]`. The former is used when in C/C++ and you don't have Objective-C. The latter follows the conventional syntax in Objective-C.